# AngularJS Intercept and extend controller $scope

Tags: angularjs

There is a lot of reusable functionality that I have defined in my application that EVERY controller uses with the $scope variable. Instead of me having to create a shared service each time, is there a way to extend the $scope variable so that I can have my extended code available everywhere?

Something like:

```
//I've tested this out and it doesn't work, but this is what I want to do.
angular.module('App',[]).config(['$scopeProvider',function($scope) {
  $scope.method1 = function() { ... };
  $scope.method2 = function() { ... };
}]);
```

Then later on:

```
var HomeCtrl = function($scope) {
  $scope.method1();
};
```

Is this possible? Or do I need to create a shared service and then have the $scope extend from that for the first line of each controller?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of `.config` try `.run`, this will do exactly what you want.

```
angular.module('App', []).run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.foo = function() {
     alert("WIN!");
  };
}]);

angular.module('App').controller('HomeCtr', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo(); #will call the alert
}]);
```

**NOTE** I have only used `module.controller` because I like it, `var HomeCtrl = function($scope) {` will have the same effect.

Comment: What if I need only group of controllers inherit rootScope and not all of them? Also, what if I want to group of controllers inherit some parent scope that is not rootScope?

Comment: all controllers will inherit rootScope because they are children.

Comment: You simply put the parent controller in html using ng-controller and the controllers specified inside of it(in html) will inherit from it `<div ng-controller="Foo"><div ng-controller="Bar"></div</div>`(Bar controller will inherit from Foo)

Comment: But while this approach works, it relies entirely on the nesting of the controllers. Instead just use a service to extend the scope.

Comment: @matsko - do you have an example of "using a service to extend the scope"?

Comment: Extending `$rootScope` does not generally work. Isolated scopes in directives do not prototypally inherit from the parent scope up to the `$rootScope` so they will not have the `foo` function. See it live [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9FFPacDY1oXXaPsREZSE?p=preview).

Comment: There is [another method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794371/can-i-or-should-i-use-a-global-variable-in-angularjs-to-store-a-logged-in-user/19795388#19795388) where you decorate the `$controller` service but it has its issues, too. Namely, scopes given to `link` functions are not extended by the this method. Bottom line... if Angular will not support it, we are doomed :P

Comment: @NikosParaskeuopoulos (sitting one meter away from me) dropped this idea on the table: `$rootScope.constructor.prototype.foo = function() { alert("WIN!"); };`. This fixes [all cases](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ah8bc8GMM2bCjC2bi6DN?p=preview). Even isolated scopes will have `foo` since they are built from the same contructor. This is merely a fix, not the suggested way, though.