# Can I or Should I use a Global variable in Angularjs to store a logged in user?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm new to angular and developing my first 'real' application. I'm trying to build a calendar/scheduling app ( source code can all be seen on [github](https://github.com/jonniedarko/zen-calendar) ) and I want to be able to change the content if there is a user logged in (i.e. display details relevant to them) but here's the catch:

1. I don't want the app to be dependent on having a logged in user ( needs to be something that can be configured to work publicly, privately or both)
2. I don't want to implement the user/login within this app if it can be avoided ( I want to eventually include my app in another app where this might be implemented but isn't necessarily implemented using any particular security frameworks or limited to any)

I had an idea of creating some global variable `user` that could be referenced through out my application, or if I had to implement a system to do it all in this app that I could do so in in some abstract way so that different options could be injected in.

some of my ideas or understanding of what I should be doing may be completely wrong and ignorant of fundamentals but I genuinely do not know what approach I should take to do this.

In case it is relevant I currently don't have any back-end but eventually hope use MongoDB for storage and nodejs for services but I also want to try keep it open-ended to allow others to use different storage/backends such as sql and php

is there away to have a global `user`variable/service that I could inject/populate from another (parent?) app?

If so what would be the best approach to do so?
If Not, why and what approach should I take and why?

### Update

I Believe from comments online and some suggestion made to me that a service would be the best option **BUT** How would I go about injecting from a parent application into this applications service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your (single) page is rendered dynamically by the server and the server knows if you are logged-in or not, then you could do the following:

Dynamically render a script tag that produces:

```
<script>
     window.user = { id: 1234, name: 'User A', isLoggedIn: true };
</script>
```

For non logged-in users:

```
<script>
     window.user = { isLoggedIn: false };
</script>
```

For convinience, copy user to a value inside angular's IOC:

```
angular.module('myApp').value('user', window.user);
```

Then, you can use it in DI:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myService', function(user) {
    return {
        doSomething: function() {
            if (user.isLoggedIn) {
                ...
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Something tricky (which you should thing twice before doing [SEE COMMENTS]) is *extending* the $scope:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$controller', function($delegate, user) {
        return function(constructor, locals) {
            locals.$scope._user = user;
            return $delegate(constructor, locals);
        };
    });
});
```

This piece of code decorates the `$controller` service (responsible for contructing controllers) and basically says that `$scope` objects prior to being passed to controllers, will be enhanced with the `_user` property.

Having it automatically $scoped means that you can directly use it any view, anywhere:

```
<div ng-if="_user.isLoggedIn">Content only for logged-in users</div>
```

This is something risky since you may end up running into naming conflicts with the original $scope API or properties that you add in your controllers.

It goes without saying that these stuff run solely in the client and they can be easily tampered. Your server-side code should always check the user and return the correct data subset or accept the right actions.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer, this was the direction I was look for, much appreciated. One quick questions, why or why not extend the scope?

Comment: Even though I use it for a couple of utility functions, I still think it's a "hack". The proper way would be to have something like a `$scopeProvider` i.e. something supported by Angular.

Comment: One more thing about extending `$scope` this way. It only applies to scopes given to controllers. Your directive's `link` function will not have an *extended* scope. Your directive's `controller`, though, will. That's another indication that it's not something consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it in $rootScope. However, I believe it's better practice to put it inside a service. Services are singletons meaning they maintain the same state throughout the application and as such are prefect for storing things like a user object. Using a "user" service instead of $rootScope is just better organization in my opinion. Although technically you can achieve the same results, generally speaking you don't want to over-populate your $rootScope with functionality.

Comment: thank you I had that suspicion, but where I am mostly confused is how might I inject into this service from an application that includes my application within it

Comment: Then I would create two angular modules. One for your app and one that just contains the user service that you can reuse across different projects. Then all you have to do is declare the "user" module as a dependency of your app module and the user service will be available to your app. e.g angular.module('myApp', ['serviceModule']). Let me know if that's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a global `user` object inside the `$rootScope` and have it injected in all your controllers by simply putting it into the arguments of the controller, just as you do with `$scope`. Then you can implement functionalities in a simple check: `if($rootScope.user)`. This allows you to model the `user` object in any way you want and where you want, acting as a global variable, inside of Angular's domain and good practices with DI.

Comment: how would I then go about injecting into this var able form the parent app? I'm struggling to find any mention of this online

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on my comment and your edit. Here is what the code would look like if you wanted to be able to re-use your user service and insert it into other apps.

```
angular.module('user', []).service('userService', [function(){
   //declare your user properties and methods
}]) 

angular.module('myApp', ['user'])
.controller('myCtrl', ['userService', '$scope', function(userService, scope){
    // you can access userService from here
}])
```

Not sure if that's what you wanted but likewise you could have your "user" module have a dependency to another "parent" module and access that module's data the same way.