# Detect change of status between services and controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am completely new to AngularJS and I have a slight problem, please note that I am still in my first few weeks of AngularJS development and I still don't understand everything so please don't laugh.

Okay, I have an Auth Module that contains a Service I call `authService`. Within `authService` I set the value `this.isAuthenticated` to determine if a user is logged in, here is a simple example of it (I have removed everything as this is working correctly.

```
this.isAuthenticated = function () {
            // i have removed a great deal of code to keep this simple but we use $http and a rest service...
           // more code then ... 
            if (loggedInUser == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        };
```

In a different Controller called `ideasCtrl` I want to check if the user is or isn't logged in and I wish to watch if there is a state change so I can act accordingly... this is part of my `ideasCtrl`

```
// please note that authService is correctly injected / referenced
$scope.isAuthenticated = authService.isAuthenticated();
    console.log($scope.isAuthenticated);

$scope.$watch('isAuthenticated', function() {
    console.log('hey, isAuthenticated has changed!');
});
```

I view my app as a public user, I then login (the login form is just a view at the top of the app which I import in using `ng-view`) `$scope.$watch('isAuthenticated'`... isn't triggered, fired or anything. How do I broadcast this or make sure that I capture the change event.

Please feel free to give me a nod in the correct direction to investigate this (like a topic or development area) if an answer cannot be provided. I realise that my code example is pretty awful.

Comment: Not totally relevant to your question: You mention you import the login form with `ng-view`. You can have only 1 `ng-view` in your page, that is the main body of your app where you load "routes" registerd in `$routeProvider`. BTW, you can check [this posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794371/can-i-or-should-i-use-a-global-variable-in-angularjs-to-store-a-logged-in-user/19795388#19795388) for an authenticated/public scenario.

Answer (score 1):

As implemented, `$scope.isAuthenticated` receives a value at initialization and holds on to it forever. So the `$watch` isn't fired again, because the watched expression never changes! Since `authService.isAuthenticated()` is quick, you can watch it directly:

```
$scope.$watch(
    function() { return authService.isAuthenticated(); },
    function(newval, oldval) {
        // state changed
    }
);
```

Comment: How can I use this if I want all my controllers to have access to this updated service value? I don't want to write a $watch every time, for each controller.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nikos noted, you are only calling `authService.isAuthenticated()` once so `$scope.isAuthenticated` won't change and that `$watch` won't do anything. However if that `authService` depends on calls to an API as you mention you won't want to run it repeatedly. I suggest emitting events on different authentication events and listening for them in your controller. For example, on a login event in your service you might do:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("auth:login");
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.$on('auth:login', function() {
  console.log('hey, isAuthenticated has changed (user logged in)!');
});
```