# Potential issues with creating $interval on scope/$scope/$rootScope

Tags: angularjs

What would be (if there is any) problems in creating something like this:

```
scope.$interval = function(callback, duration){
    var internalScope = this;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(callback()){
            internalScope.$apply();
        }
    }, duration);
    internalScope.$on("$destroy", function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
    return interval;
};
```

I'd have to run my own $apply's, that I understand but this would save me listening in on $destroy events everywhere when setting up intervals. Also I'm unfamiliar with extending scope. If i apply this instead to the $rootScope, would every scope/$scope in the entire system inherit the function?

While minor it would change

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){

}, 100);
scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

to

```
scope.$interval(function(){
    //return true to run the apply
}, 100);
```

---

As another suggestion, the same thing could be done with $timeout:

```
scope.$timeout = function(callback, duration){
    var internalScope = this;
    var interval = setTimeout(function(){
        callback();
        internalScope.$apply();
    }, duration);
    internalScope.$on("$destroy", function(){
        clearTimeout(interval);
    });
    return interval;
};
```

resulting in

```
scope.$timeout(function(){

}, 100);
```

Comment: To get your idea a bit further, why not making `$interval` a service, much like `$timeout`? I don't know the answer, I'm just wondering...

Comment: Because I don't want the $apply running every iteration. Just at specified times. I'm assuming this is why it's not baked into angular. I also want it to listen in on the scope destroy event. If I can attach it to every scope then the second function is a lot quicker.

Comment: I totally agree with you. As far as extending the `$scope` is concerned, this can be done by using a `decorator` on top of `$controller`. Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794371/can-i-or-should-i-use-a-global-variable-in-angularjs-to-store-a-logged-in-user/19795388#19795388) AND comments (use on your own risk, though).

Comment: As far as adding stuff to the `$rootScope` is concerned, -i think- it does not mean that every child `$scope` will inherit them. Isolated scopes do not inherit from `$rootScope`, they merely hold a reference to it. If it helps, check out how `$new` this implemented in class `Scope` [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js).

Comment: It seems you can extend it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956667/angularjs-intercept-and-extend-controller-scope

Comment: As I mention before, there is a problem with isolates scopes. See it [live](http://plnkr.co/edit/9FFPacDY1oXXaPsREZSE?p=preview)

Comment: Hmm.... yeah thanks. I understand the reason they don't make it easy, as the scope variable does a lot of other things.